# Issue with the Tabs in TabConatiner

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using a custom Widget PluginTabContainer:

```
<div data-dojo-type="test/PluginTabContainer" url="ConfigServlet?fileName=SettingsTabConfig.json"
```

id="tb" tabPosition="left-h" tabStrip="true">

It is calling a serlvet to fetch the data of three tabs which are places in the TabConatiner. 
On each of the tab there are some checkboxes and an update button to save the settings for the user.
When a user changes the value of a checkbox and doesn't update the settings via the update button and switch to the other tab and again comes back to the first tab then the orginal values/settings are not displayed. The settings modified by the user are shown.
If user presses F5 or close the page and opens again then everything is fine.

How can I resolve it?.
Also, how I can assign Id's to the three tabs which are placed in the TabConatiner. Those tabs are basically dojo (js and html files).

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Dojo TabContainer tab switches are not refetching the page from the server and re-rendering the page in the browser, they're using the TabContainer widget JS runtime to hide one tab (div) and show another, which is why your checkboxes are not going back to their original state on a tab switch.

To catch a tab switch and clear inputs (or whatever your use case needs on such event) take a look at the Dojo TabContainer documentation for watching tab selection events at:
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/layout/TabContainer.html#dijit-layout-tabcontainer